MongoDB Service Fails to Start on Windows with Error 1067 and ECONNREFUSED on localhost:27017
I'm facing an issue where I cannot start my MongoDB server on Windows 10. Here's what happens:

Error in MongoDB logs:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-21T18:23:54.163+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}

The last line in the logs indicates an unhandled exception:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-20T00:22:39.445+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23137,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"}



This is a link to the all log file:
Link to log file.

Connection error in my Node.js application:
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017


Windows Service error when trying to start MongoDB:
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.




Checked mongod.cfg for correct configuration. My dbPath and logPath are set as follows:
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\8.0\data\db
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\8.0\log\mongod.log


Verified the C:\data\db directory exists and has the correct permissions.

Ran MongoDB with --repair:
mongod --repair --dbpath C:\data\db

The repair completes, but MongoDB still won't start.

Checked for port conflicts on 27017 using:
netstat -ano | findstr :27017

Nothing else is using this port.

Reinstalled MongoDB and ensured that all previous MongoDB data and configuration files were deleted before reinstalling.

Tried running mongod.exe manually from the command line with administrative privileges. The error still persists.

Checked Windows Event Logs for more details but couldn't find any additional information.


Mongoose Connection Code:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydatabase");

System Info:

OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)
MongoDB Version: 8.0
Node.js: v20.18.0

Request:
How can I resolve Error 1067 and get MongoDB to start correctly on my machine? Any suggestions on what else I should check or try?

You have set
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\8.0\data\db

That means, you must verify the C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\8.0\data\db directory exists and has the correct permissions.
C:\data\db is just the default if you don't specify any storage.dbPath

Tried running mongod.exe manually

That's something different, because without a config file, it uses default parameters. You would need mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\8.0\bin\mongod.cfg"
BTW, it is maybe not the smartest choice (or at least not so common) to put data and logs under C:\Program Files\...

does not solve my problem

Hard to believe. Check the logs carefully. Do you really expect anybody to go through your thousands lines of the linked log file? Delete the file, try to start MongoDB once and read the logs
